# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, microsoft-cdn

I am getting this error in the Chrome JScript debugger.  It happened when I switched to the Microsoft CDNs for the scripts below.

I'm not sure how to work around this save, not using the CDNs anymore.

jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js:5
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

```
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-1.7-development-only.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmplPlus.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Another reason this error can occur is if you load the unobtrusive script before jquery.validate.

So,

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

is OK, but:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

will give the "Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined" error.

Answer (score 15):

Found it.  I was missing two lines:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

I learned this by [reading this page](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) which describes how the jquery.validate.unobtrusive script works.