# dotnet highcharts in MVC app: displays the only value, but must many

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

Trying to display in  MVC-app exchange rates at specific period, but always get only **one** rate value. However debugger says that all values are got correctly from data source. Think, there are problems in javascript side.This is my controller's action code:

IList dataSource = _dataProvider.SelectRatesByDateRange(curCountry,
                    crange.BeginDate, crange.EndDate).ToList();

```
            string[] dates = dataSource.Select(c => c.Date.ToShortDateString()).ToArray();
            decimal[] values = dataSource.Select(c => c.Value).ToArray();



            var chart = new Highcharts("Charts");
            chart.InitChart(new Chart {DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Areaspline})
                .SetTitle(new Title {Text = "Currency rates at specified period."})
                .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle {Text = crange.SelectedCurrencySymbol})
                .SetXAxis(new XAxis {Categories = dates, Title = new XAxisTitle {Text = "Dates"}})
                .SetYAxis(new YAxis {Title = new YAxisTitle {Text = "Currencies rates"}})
                .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                {
                    Line = new PlotOptionsLine
                    {
                        DataLabels = new PlotOptionsLineDataLabels {Enabled = true},
                        EnableMouseTracking = false
                    }
                })
                .SetSeries(new Series {Color = Color.Green, Data = new Data(new object[]{values})});

             crange.Chart  = chart;
             return View("ChartingPage", crange);
```

JS-code which is generated: (for EUR/USD pair)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var Charts;
$(document).ready(function() {
    Charts = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: { renderTo:'Charts_container', defaultSeriesType: 'areaspline' }, 
        plotOptions: { line: { dataLabels: { enabled: true }, enableMouseTracking: false } }, 
        subtitle: { text: 'EUR' }, 
        title: { text: 'Currency rates at specified period.' }, 
        xAxis: { categories: ['12.03.2014', '13.03.2014', '14.03.2014', '15.03.2014', '16.03.2014', '17.03.2014', '18.03.2014', '19.03.2014', '20.03.2014', '21.03.2014', '22.03.2014'], title: { text: 'Dates' } }, 
        yAxis: { title: { text: 'Currencies rates' } }, 
        series: [{ data: [[0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.72, 0.73, 0.72, 0.72]], color: 'green' }]
    });
});
```

Also chrome console says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined. Can this be related to graphic rendering problem?
 All ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

about JS Uncaught TypeError: got rid of it - answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911439/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined)(first answer). 
But primary problem is actual.

Comment: You can array in array in the data, it should be single array, not doubled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer: it was necessary explicitly create array of objects,  manually copy all values from **values** collection to it, and pass this array to Data of chart.