# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am getting the error when I try to load my **jquery** scripts (at the bottom of the code) in order to run my c# application with form validation. I believe I have my scripts in the right order, and all packages are also showing up in my sources once I load the page. My versions are the following. Any ideas on how to resolve the error?

"jquery": "2.1.4",
"jquery-validation": "1.15.0",
"jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "3.2.4"

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>MEC - Creative Naming Convention</title>
        <base href="/">
        <environment names="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
            <link href="~/lib/angularjs-toaster/toaster.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="~/lib/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
        </environment>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="~/scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>

        <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="/home" class="navbar-brand" target="_self"><img src="~/images/grouplogo5.png" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/home" target="_self">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/creative" target="_self">New Creative Name</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/creative/existing" target="_self">View Existing Creatives</a></li>@*"*@
                    </ul>
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_LoginPartial")
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2016 - CreativeNamingConvention</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <environment names="Development">      
            <script src="~/scripts/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment names="Staging,Production">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.5/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal">
            </script>
            <script src="~/scripts/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
        
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911439/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer! You have to put the jquery scripts before the requirejs scripts and it solves the problem!