# Asp.Net Core Client side validation is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use client side validation and its not working. My model is:

```
 [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
      public string Email { get; set; }
```

my layout used by the view has:

```
 <script src="~/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

my view has:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

when I check the form html in the browser it shows:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="email" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="Email" name="Email" value="">
        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

but when I click the submit button, the form is been posted to the server which means the client side validation is not working.

Comment: Are you *absolutely sure* that those jQuery scripts actually loaded? Do they appear okay in your browser's dev tools' Network window?

Comment: when I check the head section of the page in the browser I see tags for the 3 scripts in the head section

Comment: I didn't ask you to check the rendered HTML, I asked you to check the Network tab of your browser's dev-tools to see if the script requests failed or if your browser blocked loading it, perhaps due to some defined CSP.

Comment: I just tried refreshing the page with the network tab open and I can see the scripts are been loaded

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911439/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1):

For some reasons you have to add asp-validation-summary just below form tag

```
<form id="myForm">

<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
.....
.....
</form>
```

Comment: I already have a asp-validation-summary below my form tag like: <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>

Comment: @fake2608  try to change it to "ModelOnly"

Comment: I just tried ModelOnly and the form is still being posted to the server

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The problem was that I was loading the unobtrusive script before the jquery.validate sceipt. Found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911439/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that you should load the jquery.validate script before the unobtrusive script. Found the answer here
[Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'unobtrusive' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7911439/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-unobtrusive-of-undefined)